# python datetime gets object has no attribute today error

Tags: python, python-import, python-datetime

I have the following 2 different datetime uses:

```
date=request.GET.get('date','')
    if date:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        print date
    else:
        date = datetime.date.today()
```

It seems the imports needed are:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()
```

I can't have both:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
```

or one overrides the other.

If I have one, I get the error:
 object has no attribute today

How can I use both these datetime functions?

Comment: `import datetime` and `date = datetime.date.today()` works fine for me.

Answer (score 18):

You can alias the import names to ensure they're used differently. This is one of the reasons why datetime gets its fair share of criticism in the Python community.

What about:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import datetime
```

These will represent two separate things. AS shown by `dir(dt)` and `dir(datetime)`

Answer (score 7):

Removing `.date.` from your code should work:

```py
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.strptime("12/31/2000", "%m/%d/%Y")
print datetime.today()
```

Output:

```
2000-12-31 00:00:00
2014-08-16 22:36:28.593481
```

Answer (score 5):

In the case of datetime, you should always import the module itself, precisely to avoid this confusion.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
date = datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'date' is not defined. Did you mean: 'data'?